# Mui v5: Extend palette color to have more options

Tags: typescript, material-ui

In MUI v5, they have color options on grey from 50, 100, 200, ... to 900, I would like to extend to have more options like 1000, 1100 etc. Any help is appreciated.

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/

[image]